# Windows - How do I delete corrupted files from a folder?

Tags: windows

While deleting some files, few are corrupted and werent deleted because it says they are corrupted.

Just pressing delete is not working neither with del in CMD.

How could I do this via windows explorer or CMD?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps better to do `chkdsk` and then decide what to do with the files.

Comment: Hello, How do I do this only for that specific folder with the corrupted files?

Comment: You don't. `chkdsk` is for partitions and the suggestion to use assumes the corruption was due to logical errors in the partition they reside. So, using the error correction tool will either "uncorrupt" the files or at least let the user delete them. If other situation please [edit] the question and provide more details.

Comment: @Joao, Its important to understand that the failure to delete indicates corruption of the filesystem as regards that file, not necessarily a corruption of the file itself. The system would have no trouble deleting a corrupted file, if the filesystem metadata for that file is fine. In most circumstances deleting a file does nothing to the file at all; it just modifies the filesystem to forget about the file data, and eventually overwrites it with new file changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link is the Microsoft canonical reference for dealing with files that cannot be deleted

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume

Your circumstance falls under **Cause 3**

> **Cause 3: File system corruption is preventing access to the file**
>
> You
> may not be able to delete the file if the file system is corrupted. To
> resolve this issue, run the Chkdsk utility on the disk volume to
> correct any errors.
>
> Bad sectors on the disk, other faulty hardware, or software bugs can
> corrupt the file system and put files in a problematic state. Typical
> operations may fail in a variety of ways. When the file system detects
> corruption, it logs an event to the event log and you typically
> receive a message that prompts you to run Chkdsk. Depending on the
> nature of the corruption, Chkdsk may or may not be able to recover
> file data; however, Chkdsk returns the file system to an internally
> consistent state.
>
> For additional information about using the Chkdsk
> utility, click the following article numbers to view the articles in
> the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> [176646](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/176646) Error message: The file or
> directory is corrupt...
>
> [187941](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/187941) An explanation of CHKDSK and the New
> /C and /I switches

Comment: Just a heads up that those links (within the quoted link) no longer work.

Comment: Yeah, MS decided to rebrand and redo their developer and admin documentation (formerly msdn and technet), so most MS links before 2018 no longer work. its a real shame.